In PDFClown, is it possible to make the layers appear on top of the content
I am a newbie at PDF Clown and at pdf modification in general. I want to add some text in a new layer/OCG onto a pdf. In this code, it's to add a name and some number to the pdf. My problem is, this text/layer/OCG appears underneath the pdf content. I want to add text on top of the content. A use case for this is if the form is already filled in, I can add a white rectangle on top of the filled in part and add the text on top of the white rectangle but that won't work it this only gets added below the content. This is my code right now:
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using org.pdfclown.documents;
using org.pdfclown.documents.contents;
using org.pdfclown.documents.contents.colorSpaces;
using org.pdfclown.documents.contents.composition;
using org.pdfclown.documents.contents.fonts;
using org.pdfclown.documents.contents.layers;
using org.pdfclown.files;
using org.pdfclown.objects;

namespace PDFClownOverlayReport
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputPath = @"C:\input.pdf";
            string outputPath = @"C:\output.pdf";

            using (var file = new org.pdfclown.files.File(inputPath))
            {
                Document document = file.Document;
                Page page = document.Pages[0];

                // Ensure layer definition exists
                if (document.Layer == null)
                {
                    document.Layer = new LayerDefinition(document);
                }

                //// Create a new layer for the rectangle
                //Layer rectangleLayer = new Layer(document, "Rectangle Layer");

                //// Add the rectangle layer to the document's layer collection
                //document.Layer.Layers.Add(rectangleLayer);
                //rectangleLayer.Visible = true;

                // Create a content composer for the pagex
                PrimitiveComposer composer = new PrimitiveComposer(page);

                // Flush the existing content
                composer.Flush();

                // Begin a new content block
                composer.BeginLocalState();

                //// Begin the rectangle layer block
                //composer.BeginLayer(rectangleLayer);

                //// Set fill color to light blue for visibility
                //composer.SetFillColor(new DeviceRGBColor(0.5, 0.5, 1)); // Light blue color

                //// Draw a rectangle
                //composer.DrawRectangle(new RectangleF(105, 115, 190, 20));
                //composer.Fill();

                //// End the local state for rectangle layer
                //composer.End();

                //// Flush the content for rectangle layer
                //composer.Flush();

                // Create a new layer for the text
                Layer textLayer = new Layer(document, "Text Layer");

                // Add the text layer to the document's layer collection
                document.Layer.Layers.Add(textLayer);
                textLayer.Visible = true;

                // Begin a new content block for text layer
                composer.BeginLocalState();

                // Begin the text layer block
                composer.BeginLayer(textLayer);

                // Set font and size
                composer.SetFont(new StandardType1Font(document, StandardType1Font.FamilyEnum.Helvetica, true, false), 12);

                // Set text color to red for visibility
                composer.SetFillColor(new DeviceRGBColor(0, 0, 0)); // Red color

                // Add text on top of the rectangle
                composer.ShowText("John Smith", new PointF(106, 128));
                composer.ShowText("1234567890", new PointF(61, 147));

                // End the local state for text layer
                composer.End();

                // Flush the content for text layer
                composer.Flush();

                // Save the modified document
                file.Save(outputPath, SerializationModeEnum.Standard);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("PDF modified and saved successfully.");
        }
    }
}


I tried running the code and I expected the text to be drawn on top of the content but instead it was drawn underneath the content.

If your already filled-in forms are the normal interactive AcroForm forms, then your approach is wrong: The visualizations of form fields, the form fields widgets, are PDF annotations, and annotations are on top of anything in the regular page content. And you add your changes to the regular page content. Thus, the form field Widgets will always be drawn on top of your changes.
